# Joomla Modules jQuery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I have a jQuery conflict in two Joomla modules. I found the below code in each of the modules. Could anyone please help me to resolve the conflict?

Code in first module:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>

//...

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#jeYW<?php echo $module->id ?>').weatherfeed([<?php echo "'".$cityCode[0]."'"; for ($i=1; $i<count($cityCode); $i++){echo ",'".$cityCode[$i]."'";}?>],{
      unit: '<?php echo $unit ?>',
      image: <?php echo $image ?>,
      country: <?php echo $country ?>,
      highlow: <?php echo $highlow ?>,
      wind: <?php echo $wind ?>,
      humidity: <?php echo $humidity ?>,
      visibility: <?php echo $visibility ?>,
      sunrise: <?php echo $sunrise ?>,
      sunset: <?php echo $sunset ?>,
      forecast: <?php echo $forecast ?>,
      link: <?php echo $forecastlink ?>,
      showerror: true,
      linktarget: '_blank',
      woeid: <?php echo $woeid ?>
    });
  });
</script>
```

Code in second module:

```
$document->addScript(JURI::base(true).'/modules/mod_muscol_featured_albums/tmpl/jcarousel/lib/jquery-1.2.3.pack.js');

$document->addScript(JURI::base(true).'/modules/mod_muscol_featured_albums/tmpl/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js');

$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base(true).'/modules/mod_muscol_featured_albums/tmpl/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.css');

//...

$document->addScriptDeclaration("
  console.dir(jQuery.fn.init.prototype);
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#random_album_".$random_id."').jcarousel({
      // Configuration goes here
      scroll: ".$scroll."
      ".$auto."
      ".$animation."
      ".$circular."
      ".$vertical."
    });
});
");
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in the second module. The function on the line `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` does not have a closing brace. Was this just a typo when copying it onto Stack Overflow?

Comment: Simon,Thank you for notice yes this is just a typo while copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327). Read the reviews you will understand how great this component is. I have been using it for a long time now.

> Features:
>
> - jQuery and jQuery UI libraries can be hosted in Joomla! or called from the Google API libraries in HTTP or HTTPS (set explicit versions
>     for proper caching),
> - no coding is necessary in front or back end (no need to add code into template or mess with Joomla! core),
> - places jQuery calls AFTER MooTools calls for perfect compatibility,
> - adds the noConflict code,
> - sets up the 'jQuery' variable to 'true' at the application level,
> - strips out all other jQuery, jQuery UI library calls, including the noConflict calls added by other modules or plugins,
> - choose jQuery UI basic styling or custom theme.
> - NEW: possible expert tweaks
> - NEW: the plugin can be enabled or disabled in specific portions of your site
> - NEW since v1.2.0: MooTools libraries can be tentatively disabled in the front end
> - NEW since v1.3.0: reporting and more options to help in solving more advanced cases
> - NEW: Joomla! 3.0 specific version release

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you only have 1 copy of jQuery being imported. To do so, use this instead:

```
if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     $document = JFactory::getDocument();
     $document->addScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js");
}
```

Update:

Try adding this above the `if` statement for noConflict

```
$document->addCustomTag( '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>' );
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Lodder, 
Actually removing '/' causes files not be found.
Also I checked your 'if' code but it didn't resolve the problem.

Is there any way in Joomla to import jQuery once though the portal and don't import it on every module? maybe this can resolve the problem.

Comment: Can I use `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` to resolve the conflict?
If yes, can eny body tell me how to use it in my code?

Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer, if it doesn't work, could you please provide a link to your website?

Answer (score 0):

jquery easy should handle that problem, alternativly you can add this to the head of your template index.php :

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

that'll load jquery 1.8.1 (or whatever 1.8 version which is joomla stable)

in my case in using both, where jquery easy is just disabling mootools and adding jquery ui for me, had some conflicts and this setup seemed to solve it...